# Periodically generating CustomObject entries

Tags: custom-object, bulk, create-records

we have created a CustomObject MonthlyItem as child of Contract (Master/Detail Relationship). Now we want to generate new MonthlyItems at the end of each month for the next respective month.

Something like:

```
For each active Contract
   Create a new MonthlyItem for the contract
     Field-Begin: 1/next-month/this-year
     Field-Budget: some-contract-field
```

What is the preferred technology for this Task?

Answer (score 1):

The above scenario can be implemented using batch apex.

Also you need to implement scheduled apex to run the batch class at the end of month.

Comment: thank you - is Apex is the only solution or are flows / workflows also an option?

Comment: Using flows we can create time based action only if  there is a DML on the record.
For this requirement scheduled apex is the solution.